# Dynamically Loading Class Into Interface

Tags: c#

I'm trying to dynamically load a class, from a dll, at run time then cast it as in interface.

I have a class define in a dll called MyClass.dll like below.

```
namespace MyClass
{
    public class Class1 : IMyInterface
    {
        public int MyNumber { get; set; } = 6;

        public int GetMyNumber()
        {
            return MyNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, i have an interface defined in a shared dll like below:

```
namespace Common
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        int MyNumber { get; set; }

        int GetMyNumber();
    }
}
```

Finally, i have my code attempted to load the assembly and assign it as a IMyInterface.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fName = @"D:\Development\Research\Dynamic Load\MyClass\bin\Debug\MyClass.dll";

            Assembly decoupledAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fName);
            if (decoupledAssembly != null)  //All Good
            {
                Type t = decoupledAssembly.GetType("MyClass.Class1");
                //Good here too, it finds it just fine.
                IMyInterface mi = (Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IMyInterface);
                //Now i'm screwed screwed.
                if (mi != null)
                    MessageBox.Show(mi.GetMyNumber().ToString());                    
            }
        }
```

You can see in the comments where it is breaking.  I find the type, no problem, but returns null when I attempted to cast it as my interface.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using the same interface definition in both assemblies?

Comment: Do you have multiple `IMyInterface`s?

Comment: What is the output of `Activator.CreateInstance(t)` if you don't try to cast it? Do you get an object?

Comment: Yes, the interface is stored in a shared dll/project.  But the windows application and the dll are referencing that project to get the interface.

Comment: The output of CreateInstance is MyClass.Class1

Comment: So it's the cast that is going wrong. That means it doesn't implement `IMyInterface`, or at least it doesn't implement the same `IMyInterface` as you are expecting.

Comment: Try doing getType on the uncast instance and inspecting the interfaces it implements using type.GetInferfaces()

Comment: Got it figured.  I had to reference the full path to my interface.  Even though both projects where referencing the same namespace.  I think that's a .net bug personally, but anyways.  Thanks for your time, everyone.

Comment: Can you update your question or answer yourself how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the full path to the interface.  Strange, but once I did this it started working.  See the changes below.

```
namespace MyClass
{
    public class Class1 : Common.IMyInterface
    {
        public int MyNumber { get; set; } = 6;

        public int GetMyNumber()
        {
            return MyNumber;
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fName = @".....\MyClass.dll";

            Assembly decoupledAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fName);
            if (decoupledAssembly != null)  //All Good
            {
                Type t = decoupledAssembly.GetType("MyClass.Class1");
                //Good here too, it finds it just fine.
                Common.IMyInterface mi = (Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Common.IMyInterface);
                //Now it works.
                if (mi != null)
                    MessageBox.Show(mi.GetMyNumber().ToString());                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you saying that changing the value of fName did the trick? I just mocked up your code and it worked as originally proposed - no change. Perhaps you had not built the dll?